# Why do I get "URL not found" when I try to run my CGI script?

Tags: apache, perl, cgi, mod-perl

I am setting up my Windows 7 machine to host a Perl CGI script using the following Apache configuration:

```
<Directory "C:\Users\username\Documents\web">
    AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch Includes ExecCGI
    <Limit GET POST OPTIONS PROPFIND>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Limit>
    <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS PROPFIND>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

However, when I try to access the following URL, I get "URL not found". How can I fix this?

```
http://localhost/~username/test.cgi
```

Answer (score 0):

What does it say in your web server error log?

I suspect that you haven't configured [per-user web directories](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/public_html.html). They are turned off by default. And they are required for Apache to understand a URL containing a tilde.